# npm ERR! code EISGIT react-native-safe-area-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

In my react native project I am not able to install any new packages because of this dumb error!

I tried deleting it manually and I tried some commands like `rm -rf node_modules/**/*/.git/` but without "-rf" because windows doenst know that!

Really need your help guys!

```sh
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! path C:\Dev\Programmierung\Schulprojekt\node_modules\react-native-paper\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! git C:\Dev\Programmierung\Schulprojekt\node_modules\react-native-paper\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-view: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.   
npm ERR! git     C:\Dev\Programmierung\Schulprojekt\node_modules\react-native-paper\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Dev\npm\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-13T06_47_21_905Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: You can try `rd /s /q node_modules` for Windows. But it seems to be a repo error. Try running `yarn add react-native-safe-area-view`

Comment: i dotn have yarn

Comment: You can use `npx yarn add react-native-safe-area-view `

Comment: what do i have to type then? npx install doesnt exist

Comment: You type what I just wrote above. `npx` lets you use a package without installing it. Here, you're using yarn to install `react-native-safe-area-view`

Comment: mh alright this actually seems to work. ty mike